# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor when link two python files by os.pipe()

Tags: python, file, unix

I have two python files with os.read() and os.write() in each other. I need to write from one script to another by os.pipe between them.

write.py

```
import json
import os, sys, time

# file descriptors r, w for reading and writing
r, w = os.pipe() # r = 3, w = 4

while True:

    try:
        message = json.dumps({"text":"Text written by child!!!"})
        print("Child writing: ", message)
        os.write(w, bytes(message, "utf-8"))
        time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        os.close(w)

        print("Child closing")

        sys.exit(0)
```

file2.py

```
import os, sys, json

print("The child will write text to a pipe and ")
print("the parent will read the text written by child... ")

resp = os.read(3, 1000)
resp = json.loads(resp)
print(resp)
```

but I can read data from file object if run this code in file1.py

How to read from file2.py?

Comment: How are you running `file2.py`? It needs to be a child process of `write.py` so that it inherits the file descriptors that were created by `os.pipe()`.

Comment: Why are you calling `os.pipe()` yourself, instead of using the `subprocess` module?

Comment: You can't just pass a random integer, such as `3`, to `os.read` for the file descriptor, even if it happens to be the same numeric value as the other end of the pipe. The process must open the file first, or inherit the descriptor from its parent, such as by calling `os.fork()`. But the real solution here is to use the `subprocess` or `multiprocessing` modules instead, which handle all of the low-level guts for you and allow you to just send Python objects.